# A bounded function $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous outside the Cantor set is integrable

Tags: integration

Let $P$ be the Cantor set in $[0, 1]$. Let $f$: $[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function, continuous outside $P$, we have to show that $f$ is integrable.

We know that the Cantor set is uncountable and closed and there is a theorem that says if $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a rectangle and  $f: Q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function and let $D= \{x \in Q : f$ is discontinuous in $x \}$ then $\int_{Q}f$ exists if and only if $D$ has zero measure in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I would have to prove that the set of cantor has measure zero and using the theorem would have that $\int_{Q} f$ exists which means that $f$ is integrable? Or my reasoning is not right?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, assuming you have that theorem available. One way to prove that the Cantor set has zero measure is to prove that its complement in $[0,1]$ has measure $1$. The measure of the complement can easily be computed because it is a countable disjoint union of open intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is right, so now you would just need to prove the Cantor set has measure zero.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/860122)

Comment: @XanderHenderson The questions are posed in the last two sentences of the OP. This answer provides answers to those.